# When is the sum of a non-convex function with a quadratic function convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

I am looking for conditions on parameters $a$ and $b$ and on non-convex function $g$ such that the scalar function

$$f(x) = a g(x) + \frac b2 x^2$$

is convex. It would be a great help if someone can guide me on this problem.

Comment: is $g$ concave? What can you tell us about $g$?

Comment: The first-order characterization of convexity requires that $f(y)-f(x)\ge f’(x)(y-x)$ for all $x,y$ in the domain. Playing with this might help (assuming $g$ is differentiable)

Comment: Dear Rodrigo de Azevedo, the function g(x) is non-convex.

Comment: @user571754 you're missing Rodrigo's point. If the _only thing you can say_ about $g$ is that it is non-convex, then there are no conditions _at all_ you can place on $a$ and $b$, except perhaps $a=0, b>0$. You need to offer something more: e.g., $g$ is continuous and twice-differentiable.

Comment: Thanks Michael! You are exactly right. We may assume that g is continuous and twice-differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to (or can always) choose $a>0$, and $g$ is twice differentiable on an open interval, then you obtain your result on that interval if $$g''>-b.$$

Comment: Only if you're already assuming $g$ to be differentiable...

Comment: @MichaelGrant Yes, obviously. This is *one* of the conditions on $g$ OP asked for.